# meteor listen for multiple events fire just once

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, meteor

Meteor offers to define eventHandlers for templates. I have a text input that a user can type, but also paste in etc.

Sofar I have used:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    'keyup #inputfield': function() {
         DO SOMETHING HERE
     }
});
```

Is it possible to define something similar to jquery's "on" function?

```
$('#inputfield').on('change keypress paste focus textInput input', function () 
{ 
    DO SOMETHING HERE
});
```

This will fire only once regardless of how many of the events occur at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stopImmediatePropagation` to stop additional handers:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    'keyup #inputfield': function(event) {
         event.stopImmediatePropagation();
     }
});
```

or you could use jQuery plus the `rendered` command to achieve the same thing:

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered(function() {
  $(this.find('#inputField')).on('change keypress paste focus textInput input', function () 
  { 
      DO SOMETHING HERE
  });
});
```

Comment: I was hoping I would get around your second suggestion and stay in the 'meteor' style world ( just to keep my code clean ). The first one is interesting, thx!

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer or upvote if it's at least helpful, thanks! :P

Answer (score 1):

[`_.throttle`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) should do the trick:

```
var handler = _.throttle(function(event) {
    ...
}, 1, {leading: false});


Template.myTemplate.events({
    'event event anotherEvent': handler,
});
```

Comment: Interesting, but you'd want to bind the context.

Comment: Soon Meteor will be made aware of jquery events, but it is not for now.  Debugging what template refresh trashed your jquery events does not sound productive, so this is a safer solution